# How to filter a list in C# with lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to filter a list so it results in a list with just the brisbane suburb?

c#

```
Temp t1 = new Temp() { propertyaddress = "1 russel street",  suburb = "brisbane" };
            Temp t2 = new Temp() { propertyaddress = "12 bret street", suburb = "sydney" };
            List<Temp> tlist = new List<Temp>();
            tlist.Add(t1);
            tlist.Add(t2);

            List<Temp> tlistFiltered = new List<Temp>();
            //tlistFiltered. how to filter this so the result is just the suburbs from brisbane?

public class Temp
    {
        public string propertyaddress { get; set; }
        public string suburb { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `Where` clause to filter a sequence

```
 var tlistFiltered = tlist.Where(item => item.suburb == "brisbane")
```

LINQ expressions like Where return `IEnumerable<T>`. I usually capture the result with var but you could use `ToList()` to project the result to a list as well. Just depends what you need to do with the list later.

```
List<Temp> tlistFiltered = tlist
    .Where(item => item.suburb == "brisbane")
    .ToList()
```

Note that with the above you don't have to allocate a new list. The `Where` and `ToList()` methods both return a new sequence which you just need to capture with the reference.